# Working .htaccess in windows IIS handler

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, iis

I have installed PHP 5 via Web Platform Installer on my windows 8 but did not install apache. PHP files are working now. *Handler Mapping* are including ***.php** extensions.

I want to use **.htaccess** files but Rewrite settings are not workin. Should I do some settings on IIS? Or how can understant that .htaccess is working?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use .htaccess directly as IIS doesn't support this format but there are third party utilities which can convert your files to web.config files, [example here](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig).
[Utility here](http://www.htaccesstowebconfig.com/).

Alternatively, see [How to redirect a URL path in IIS?](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/6b855a7a-0884-4508-ba95-079f38c77017.mspx?mfr=true)